# selenium driver,get() automatically redirected another page

Tags: python, linux, docker, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently making an auto scraper using selenium in docker ubuntu container

while i doing it, i found that i couldn't access a specific url in that website, i tried to driver.get() to that url but the server automatically redirect another server. maybe it's a security action to prevent scrawling bot from doing it

At first i guessed is was the problem of using headless chrome driver, but i tried to run the code on window and it worked.
how can i solve this problem?

this is my chromedirver options in ubuntu docker contianer (not working version)

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument("--user-agent=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/111.0.5563.65 Safari/537.36")
```

and this is the ubuntu container dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt install wget
RUN apt install unzip
RUN apt-get install vim -y
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt -y install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/` curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN mkdir chrome
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/src/chrome

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["uvicorn","main:app","--reload","--host=0.0.0.0","--port=8000"]
```

and this is window version chromedriver options

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

like i said same code work on window (except chrome options, slightly different but almost same)
i want to know how to fix that problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it could be possible that the website detects your Selenium-driver as a bot and is instead redirecting you to another page. You could try to fix this by mimicking user behavior by changing certain options in the ChromeDriver. What I would do is: I would modify the User-Agent Header (which a lot of websites use to detect bots) to mimic a normal user's browser, and add some delays in between the requests.

Here is an example of what I'm saying:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# custom User-Agent header
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3")

# new ChromeDriver with modified options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# delays between requests
driver.get('https://example.com')
time.sleep(5)
driver.get('https://example.com/page1')
time.sleep(5)
driver.get('https://example.com/page2')
time.sleep(5)
```

Hopefully you can apply this to your code, if not, I'm sorry.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it is not working, i guess that the website think of my selenium in docker container as some kind of mobile endpoint. in my iphone i also can't access the specific url and the website redirect me to the same url